# Add Conditional background color to excel sheet using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I have been trying to apply background color to my pandas data frame and save it to an excel file using style.apply() but I don't see the background color being applied in my excel file. I have tried many ways but the result is same.

My Data:

| ID | Start Time | End Time | Time_Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-04 12:14:59 | 2022-12-04 12:29:05 | 14 |
| 2 | 2022-12-04 12:44:32 | 2022-12-04 12:57:54 | 13 |

Here I'm trying to apply the background color to the whole row in the excel file based on the value in Time_Difference column

Below is my Code:

```
df_data = pd.read_sql(DATA_FETCH_QUERY, con=self.database_util.db_conn)
df_data.style.apply(lambda x: [
            'background:red' if x > 15 else ('background:yellow' if 10 < x <= 15 else 'background:white') for
            x in df_data.TIME_DIFFERENCE], axis=0)
df_data.to_excel(FILE_PATH, index=False)
```

Is there any issue with the code that I'm missing?

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use function with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and [`Styler.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) with new DataFrame for coloring per rows:

```
def coloring(x):
    c1 = 'background-color:red'
    c2 = 'background-color:white'
    c3 = 'background-color:yellow'

    arr = np.select([x['TIME_DIFFERENCE'] > 15, 
                     x['TIME_DIFFERENCE'] < 10],
                     [c1, c2], default=c3)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(arr[:, None], x.shape),
                        index=x.index,
                        columns=x.columns)

styler = df_data.style.apply(coloring, axis=None).hide()

styler.to_excel(FILE_PATH, engine='openpyxl')
```